# VB.NET - Convert joyGetDevCaps function from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, pinvoke, joystick

I am clueless how I should convert the following API to VB.NET

```
Private Const MAXPNAMELEN As Long = 32&

Private Type JOYCAPS
wMid As Integer
wPid As Integer
szPname As String * MAXPNAMELEN
wXmin As Long
wXmax As Long
wYmin As Long
wYmax As Long
wZmin As Long
wZmax As Long
wNumButtons As Long
wPeriodMin As Long
wPeriodMax As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function joyGetDevCaps Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "joyGetDevCapsA" (ByVal id As Long, lpCaps As JOYCAPS, ByVal uSize As Long) As Long
```

I tried some converters, but what they output was not working.
If anybody is really good, could he try to convert it for me and show me how to call it? 
Especially, I don't know how to instantiate the JOYCAPS when passing it to the function.

I did not find this function on pinvoke.net.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it, but this should be the straightforward conversion:

```
Private Const MAXPNAMELEN As Integer = 32

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure JOYCAPS
    Public wMid As Short
    Public wPid As Short
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=MAXPNAMELEN)>
        Public szPname As String
    Public wXmin As Integer
    Public wXmax As Integer
    Public wYmin As Integer
    Public wYmax As Integer
    Public wZmin As Integer
    Public wZmax As Integer
    Public wNumButtons As Integer
    Public wPeriodMin As Integer
    Public wPeriodMax As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("winmm.dll")>
Private Shared Function joyGetDevCaps(id As IntPtr, ByRef lpCaps As JOYCAPS, uSize As UInteger) As Integer

End Function
```

It assumes `System.Runtime.InteropServices` is imported.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Could you please show me how to instantiate the JOYCAPS when passing it to the function? I guess that is what you meant by "Make sure to initialize szPname to a New StringBuffer with a capacity of MAXPNAMELEN". I am not sure how I should do that.

Comment: And could you please tell me what StringBuffer is? Did you mean StringBuilder?

Comment: @tmighty: I did indeed mean StringBuilder, and it's also not right :) I edited it, and it should work fine as-is now. Just `Dim caps As New JOYCAPS()` to create an instance of the structure.

Comment: @minitech The first function param should be [pointer-sized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd757105(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @minitech Thank you! But could you show me an example of how this is actually called? Is it Dim JC As New JOYCAPS : Dim i as integer = JoyGetDevCaps(0, JC, Marshal.SizeOf(JC)) ?

Comment: @tmighty: Looks right (although the 0 should be `IntPtr.Zero`); does it work? :) What's the original VB6 code?

Comment: @minitech I am flying blind here... There seemed to be a bug on Win7 64 bit (not sure if it depends on Win7 or 64 bit). joyGetDevCaps does never return <> JOYERR_NOERROR, not even in VB6.

Comment: @minitech However, I was using             Dim JC As JOYCAPS
            Dim lRet&
            lRet = joyGetDevCaps(lFirstValidID, JC, Len(JC))
            If lRet <> JOYERR_NOERROR Then
                'This fails for me under Windows 7
                m_bConnected = True 'just say that the joystick is connected... JoystickCount seems to be valid, so we know how many buttons we got
            Else
                m_lXMax = ...
 end if

Comment: @tmighty: It probably failed on 64-bit Windows because the pointer size was hard-coded at 32-bits (hence IntPtr here). So you should pass `lFirstValidID` instead of `IntPtr.Zero` as the first argument, I suppose...

Comment: @minitech Here is my code to evaluate lFirstValidID:     Dim iDevCount  As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim JI As JOYINFO

    iDevCount = joyGetNumDevs  'All devices, even buttons

    Dim lFirstValidID&
    lFirstValidID = -1

    Do While iDevCount > 0
       iDevCount = iDevCount - 1
        If joyGetPos(iDevCount, JI) = JOYERR_NOERROR Then
            lFirstValidID = iDevCount
            JoystickCount = JoystickCount + 1
        End If
    Loop
    However, both VB6 and VB.NET return lRet = 165 for me, so I guess the code is the same.

Comment: If I set your reply as "correct answer", this thread will be closed. I will just wait some 15 minutes, perhaps somebody wants to say something about the result "165" (which I find strange).

Comment: @tmighty: What does it return on 32-bit Windows? (Or is 165 "right", but it just seems arbitrary?)

Comment: @minitech on Windows 32 bit (sorry, I only have XP 32 bit to test here), it return JOYERROR_NOERROR (=0). 165 is JOYERROR_ERRPARAMS (which means invalid joystick handle).

Comment: @tmighty: Huh. I have no clue :D Do you have any documentation I could look at?